# Chrome refuses to send Accept-Encoding gzip (even without CORS)

Tags: google-chrome, cors, gzip

The xhr request says "Provisional headers are shown" while the response has CORS headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

[image]

Also I tried using the same port (so technically no CORS is needed). The issue persist. Oddly, when I use a domain name instead of the ip, sometimes the issue would be gone (but not always).

While "Provisional headers are shown" is presented, request header won't send `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` to the server, disabling the compression.

Let me be clear, I didn't set `Accept-Encoding` for my requests. I said, `Accept-Encoding` won't be sent when "Provisional headers are shown" is presented.

Comment: Accept-Encoding is a "forbidden header name" https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name That means browsers won't let you set it in your frontend JavaScript code. It's one of the request headers that browsers control themselves. That is, it's essentially a reserved header ー reserved by browsers for their own use.

Comment: Let me be clear, I didn't set Accept-Encoding for my requests. I said, Accept-Encoding won't be sent when "Provisional headers are shown" is presented.

Comment: When you see  "Provisional headers are shown", it almost always means the browser isn't (re)sending a request for the resource over the network but is instead either (re)loading a previously-cached response from the browser cache, or else the entire request is getting canceled. Check the Network pane in browser devtools.

Comment: @sideshowbarker it is an xhr request so I doubt it is cached...also I did receive data just not compressed data.

Comment: In fact XHR requests do get cached by browsers. Very often. And the browser caches the uncompressed data, because the browser itself automatically decompresses it. In general, when the browser retrieves receives any compressed response, is not going to store the raw compressed response; instead it's going to store the uncompressed result ー because that avoids the cost of re-decompressing it each and every time it's reloaded from the cache.

Comment: How then did the xhr request return different result each time I make a request?

Comment: Ok, yeah, if it's returning a different result each time then of course those times it's clearly not being loaded from the cache

Comment: Yes but "Provisional headers are shown" is presented (only in Chrome) and the result is not compressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug. Even when the request is different, the browser thinks it is a cached request while only partially sending the request as a cached xhr (it doesn't send the headers but it sends the body).

The resolution: adding a random string in the header.